# Run exe with files from zip archive as arguments

Tags: c#, .net, cmd, zip

This seems to be a pretty specific issue, and I can't seem to find any completely related solutions (or at least don't know what to search for).

So, I've got a program which opens nested zip archives and finds specific files. From one of these file types I need to extract the relevant data using an old C program, which I've compiled to an .exe and included in the project. However, its a command line program, where the relative file paths are entered as arguments. In my code, the files come in the form of bytestreams, due to the fact that the archives are to large to extract as a whole.

I can't seem to find any clues as to how I would go about handling these streams so that the program could extract take them without unpacking. Currently my code is as follows:

```
foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
{
    if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".fileending", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        filePresent = true;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "fileExtract.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = ?
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

Are there any way of doing what I'm attempting, or do I need to find another approach?

Comment: Since you can have your files (even as bytestream) did you try to write the bytestream into a temp file, pass the temp file location in your argument and when your work is done delete all temps?  or this approach doesn't work for you?
Assuming that the bytestream is the desired file with your ".fileending" extension....

Comment: Writing to a temp file seems to defeat the purpose of not extracting the file, or is there a difference here? Otherwise it seems to me I might as well just extract to a temp location, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Since the c program is command line, and is written to operate on files given their paths, there is no way to pass streams to it as currently written. The only option that I can see would be to replicate the c program's functionality in your c# program, modified such that it can operate on streams directly.

Comment: Seems that the path of least resistance here might be to simply write the stream to a file, and use that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the "old C program" to read from stdin?

Comment: Possibly, I'm not sure. Would that enable me to read the stream directly?

Answer (score 0):

Since the old C program needs to read from the filesystem, you'll have to make a file somewhere (use System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName maybe?) and feed that path to the program.

Alternatively, rewrite the old C program to use stdin as if it were a file, though you may bump into encoding issues and maybe a contradictory 'how do I tell it the file name?' moment :P